# How to increase the slider length in d3.js

Tags: html, css, d3.js

I am working on a d3 chart with slider. I would like to increase the length of the slider.

```
<div id="content">
<br>
<!--<label class ="left" id="lblValue" text-align="left">&nbsp;&nbsp; Values: </label>-->
<br>
 <label for="RAG" text-align="center">&nbsp;&nbsp; January  -     December </label>
    <br>
<input type="range" name="dataset" value="RAG" in="1" max="12" step="1"  onchange="getData" style="margin=0" width="100px"/>
<br>
                <span class="tick" style="display:inline-block;width: 4px;text-align:left;margin-right:3px; margin-top=3px;">|<br/>1</span>
                <span class="tick" style="display:inline-block;width: 4px;text-align:center;margin-right: 3px;margin-top=3px;">|<br/>2</span>
                <span class="tick" style="display:inline-block;width: 4px;text-align:center;margin-right: 3px;margin-top=3px;">|<br />3</span>
                <span class="tick" style="display:inline-block;width: 4px;text-align:center;margin-right: 3px;margin-top=3px;">|<br />4</span>
                <span class="tick" style="display:inline-block;width: 4px;text-align:center;margin-right: 3px;margin-top=3px;">|<br />5</span>
                <span class="tick" style="display:inline-block;width: 4px;text-align:center;margin-right: 3px;margin-top=3px">|<br />6</span>
                <span class="tick" style="display:inline-block;width: 4px;text-align:center;margin-right: 3px;margin-top=3px">|<br />7</span>
                <span class="tick" style="display:inline-block;width: 4px;text-align:center;margin-right: 3px;">|<br />8</span>
                <span class="tick" style="display:inline-block;width: 4px;text-align:center;margin-right: 3px;">|<br />9</span>
                <span class="tick" style="display:inline-block;width: 4px;text-align:center;margin-right: 3px;">|<br />10</span>
                <span class="tick" style="display:inline-block;width: 4px;text-align:center;margin-right: 3px;">|<br />11</span>
                <span class="tick" style="display:inline-block;width: 4px;text-align:center;margin-right: 3px;">|<br />12</span>

</div>
```

I have created a fiddle for this:
http://jsfiddle.net/ThomsonKrish/KZGd5/1/

Also it would be great if i could align the ticks little bit top so that it displays the ticks immediately below the slider.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Width**

Instead of using `width=""` use the style property to determine the width of the slider.

For example:

```
<input type="range" name="dataset" value="RAG" in="1" max="12" step="1"  onchange="getData" style="margin: 0; width: 200px;"/>
```

**Tick positioning**

To change the positioning of the ticks, you can apply a `margin-top: -x;` property to the `.tick` class via CSS.

Comment: I tried the same.It seems to not work. I have updated the fiddle and tried running there too.

Comment: Try again and update the fiddle, my answer was edited shortly after posting - copied and pasted the incorrect answer. The example should work :).